# Game 'Blinken' is not working on Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: gnome, 22.04

When I start 'Blinken' in terminal I receive the error message:

```
*******:~$ blinken
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
kf.dbusaddons: Couldn't register name 'org.kde.blinken-17440' with DBUS - another process owns it already!
```

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: By any chance was it installed through `snap`? Or as usual? Does it appear in `dpkg -l blinken`?

Comment: It was installed from snap package.

Comment: I see. From *my experience*, `snap` packages have a record of being poorly constructed, because `snap` *(and `flatpak` for that matter, but the latter usually works better)* provides sandboxing, which is good on its own, however people who construct such packages don't always take into account all usecases, resulting in weird faults. So, try removing `blinken`, then installing it from `apt` and see if that helps. If that does, then please report a bug to the `snap` Blinken package to make sure maintainer is aware of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I have reinstalled it from .deb package.

Comment: Nice! Will write that as an answer then in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was found in comments, the problem turns out to be a bug in `snap` version of Blinken.

So the solution is to remove Blinken, and then install it back but this time from the main Ubuntu repository *(not from `snap`)*, for example as:

```bash
$ sudo apt install blinken
```

Also, please report a bug to the maintainer of `snap`-version of the Blinken package.

**N.B**: from my experience, `snap` packages have a record of being poorly constructed, because `snap` *(and `flatpak` for that matter, but the latter usually works better)* provides sandboxing, which is good on its own, however people who assemble such packages don't always take into account all usecases, resulting in weird faults. For example, docker on snap [has this unresolved problem](https://github.com/docker-snap/docker-snap/issues/34). Bear that in mind if you encounter similar problems in the future.